# What's the correct way to read ISomething : ISomethingElse

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Please forgive me if this is a very dumb question but I'm looking for clarification on how to interpret the following into plain English (assuming ISomethingElse is an existing interface):

```
public interface ISomething : ISomethingElse {
}
```

Would I read that as:

"Public interface ISomething **INHERITS** interface ISomethingElse"

or

"Public interface ISomething **IMPLEMENTS** interface ISomethingElse"

I'm leaning towards "inherits" because I've always understood an interface to be a "contract" for something, not an "implementation" but I'm just not sure what's the proper way.

I'm concerned primarily with C# (if that makes a difference).

Comment: interface doesnt implement - so its got to be inherits (extends?)

Comment: ISomething extends ISomethingElse

Comment: Java makes this relationship more explicit using the `extends` keyword when one interface inherits from another, and `implements` when a class inherits from an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# 5.0 specification uses "inherits". From §13, "Interfaces":

> An interface defines a contract. A class or struct that **implements** an interface must adhere to its contract. An interface may **inherit** from multiple base interfaces, and a class or struct may **implement** multiple interfaces.

(Emphasis added.)